# how to fix div when scrolling (relative to two other divs)?

Tags: html, css

So I have three different divs, all three should stay visible when scrolling (so `correspondence-nav`, `title` and `text-views` should stay visible when scrolling). The text-view div is scrollable itself aswell.
The first two do stay visible, I added the position sticky with an top offset.
But the third one fails and just scrolls to the top. My code so far:

HTML:

```css
.correspondence-nav{
  background:green;
  text-align:center;
  width:280px;
  }
  
  .entity-view {
            height: 100vh;
            max-width: 100vw;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            padding: 45px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    
        .title{
          margin-bottom: 1em;
          position: sticky;
          position: -webkit-sticky;
          top: 73px;
    
        }
   
        .correspondence-nav{
          position: sticky;
          position: -webkit-sticky;
          top: 20px;
        }
    
        .text-views {
            display: grid;
            height: 100vh;
            grid-auto-flow: column;
            max-width: 100vw;
            position: sticky;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            top: 100px;
        }
        .reading-version {
            grid-column: span 1.42;
        }
    
        .marginal {
            position: relative;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="entity-view">
          <div class = "correspondence-nav">
           Correspondence Nav 
          </div>
          <div class ="title" id="idHeader">
               <h1>Title</h1>
           </div>
           <div class="text-views">
                <div class="reading-version">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                </div>
                <div class="marginal">
                    Marginal Column. 
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

As you can see the `text-view` scrolls and doesn't stop under the `title` as I intended.
Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please provide a sample that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: you should be able to run the code snippet now (in full screen :) ). Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

see the sticky define: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky

> Note that a sticky element "sticks" to its nearest ancestor that has a "scrolling mechanism"

This is worked.

```css
.correspondence-nav{
  background:green;
  text-align:center;
  width:280px;
  }
  
  .entity-view {
            height: 100vh;
            max-width: 100vw;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            padding: 45px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    
        .title{
          margin-bottom: 1em;
          position: sticky;
          position: -webkit-sticky;
          top: 73px;
    
        }
   
        .correspondence-nav{
          position: sticky;
          position: -webkit-sticky;
          top: 20px;
        }
    
        .text-views {
            display: grid;
            height: 100vh;
            grid-auto-flow: column;
            max-width: 100vw;
            position: sticky;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            top: 100px;
        }
        .reading-version {
            grid-column: span 1.42;
        }
    
        .marginal {
            position: relative;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="entity-view">
          <div class = "correspondence-nav">
           Correspondence Nav 
          </div>
          <div class ="title" id="idHeader">
               <h1>Title</h1>
           </div>
           <div class="text-views">
                <div class="reading-version">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                </div>
                <div class="marginal">
                    Marginal Column. 
                </div>
            </div>
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: so you just added an additional div underneath - but what if I don't want that? I don't really understand why the title or correspondence-nav div are sticky but the reading-view breaks the flow…?

Comment: You check it the `sticky` define. It need its nearest ancestor that has a "scrolling mechanism" to be a reference. If your all elements are sticky. That will use the last element as a reference.  So the third element is not sticky.